# Pokemon Mystery Dungeon: Gates to Infinity - How much content does the DLC give you?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon

The DLC's you can buy for 1.50/2.50/3.00 euro. Do they supply any rare items, a huge amount of money (from the gold dungeon), do they have any content that the game doesn't?

Comment: Just to let you know I've flagged this as opinion based - you maybe able to rescue the question by rephrasing it, maybe by asking what the DLC grants you?

Comment: In the actual question I mention rare items, huge amount of money etc. A rare item is a rare item for all, that ain't really an opinion. But thanks for letting me know. I'll look into rewording it.

Comment: "Are they worth getting" is an opinion-based question. "How much content does the DLC give you" isn't.

Comment: @Charkz yup, hense my suggestion to try rewording it, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered. I don't know the content of the DLC or the game well enough to reword it myself but you maybe able to :)

Comment: Reworded now. See if that's any better.

Comment: Question title is better, but the content isn't ("are they worth getting", "in your own opinions")

Comment: edited it there now taking out any variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post:](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/683850-pokemon-mystery-dungeon-gates-to-infinity/66585294)

Each DLC gives 3 things.

A] 1 dungeon. Usually with a special gimmick to make the game a little easier by providing easier access to something that you can already get playing without the DLC (recruitable starters, buyable TMs, etc). There is also a 99 floor DLC dungeon if a bigger challenge after clearing the postgame dungeons is more your thing.

B] 1 Music Track used for the new dungeon and also doubles as a track that gets rotated into the main/title menu screen music.

C] 1 Music track that gets rotated into the main menu music.